# RequestError Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain - Percy Visual Tests

Tags: npm, cypress, browserstack

Percy isn't working for me for visual tests. I am getting an error -

```
> percy exec -- node ./run-tests.js

[percy] RequestError Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain | Thu Oct 29 2020 14:46:52 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
[percy] stopping percy...
[percy] waiting for 0 snapshots to complete...
[percy] done.
[percy] percy has started.
Server is listening on http://localhost:8000

[percy] stopping percy...
[percy] waiting for 0 snapshots to complete...
[percy] done.
Terminate batch job (Y/N)? y
```

Tried many things like below (`.npmrc`) but none worked -

1. ca=
2. strict-ssl=false
3. registry=http://registry.npmjs.org/
4. Setting proxy and https-proxy

Answer (score 0):

For my organization this was caused by our man-in-the-middle web filter. To get around it you need to point NPM to a copy of your company's web filter certificate by setting the path to the file in the NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS environment variable.

The certificate needs to be exported into a Base64 format. When you view it in a text editor, you'll see BEGIN CERTIFICATE and END CERTIFICATE at the top and bottom.